# Android - getting jsonobject out of jarray

Tags: android, json, wcf

I have a jsonarray thats return from a wcf I have set up that looks like this

```
["{\r\n  \"globalID\": \"104\",\r\n  \"localID\": \"1\"\r\n}","{\r\n  \"globalID\": \"105\",\r\n  \"localID\": \"2\"\r\n}","{\r\n  \"globalID\": \"106\",\r\n  \"localID\": \"3\"\r\n}","{\r\n  \"globalID\": \"107\",\r\n  \"localID\": \"4\"\r\n}","{\r\n  \"globalID\": \"108\",\r\n  \"localID\": \"5\"\r\n}","{\r\n  \"globalID\": \"109\",\r\n  \"localID\": \"6\"\r\n}"]
```

The problem Im having is that when I try to use jsonarray.optJsonObject(i) in my loop I get a null JSONObject. I know it has something to do with the extra returns but Im having a hard time figuring out how to format everything.

Comment: please show relevant part of code which you are using for JSON parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Instead of using jsonarray.optjsonobject(i) I was able to use jsonarray.optString(i) which pulled a clean string which I could then turn into a json object like this:

```
if(resultJArray!=null && resultJArray.length()>0){

    for(int i = 0; resultJArray.length()>i; i++){

      JSONObject resultJO = new JSONObject(resultJArray.optString(i));

    }
```